# Is it possible to create a stack in Matter.js using Sprites with JSON hitboxes?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, matter.js

I want to build a bridge in Phaser using stacks but not with basic geometric shapes.

I can code in each part manually, but a stack or chain would make more sense.

```
//this is almost exactly the same as from the Phaser labs
this.bridge = this.matter.add.stack(this.gameW/2, 500, 15, 1, 0, 0, function(x, y) {
    return Phaser.Physics.Matter.Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x - 50, y, 53, 20, { 
        collisionFilter: { group: group },
        chamfer: 5,
        density: 0.005,
        frictionAir: 0.05
    });
});
```

I want to replace all the rectangles with a custom sprite.

Comment: It looks like there could be a bug in the way Phaser processes the render options of Matterjs Bodies. Can't get a sprite or fillStyle render option to work.